# Replace specific character sequence after specific character

Tags: java, regex

I have the folowing string for example:

```
O > O §o TEXT §r §o TEXT §r
```

I need to replace **all** `§r` with `§r§a` **only after `>` character**.

It should be

```
O > O §o TEXT §r§a §o TEXT §r§a
```

as the result.

I tried **>*(\§r)** regex but it ignores **>**.

May You point on my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to split it into two strings first and then run a `replace`. That is, you could take

```
int index = inputString.indexOf('>') + 1;
String first = inputString.subString(0, index);
String second = inputString.subString(index);
String finalString = first + second.replace("§r", "§r§a");
```

Doing this with a pure regular expression would be difficult.

Comment: Yes; but you might also want to check that `>` is in the string first; this code would replace all `§r` in a string which doesn't.

Comment: @AndyTurner this is correct. I left out the failsafe checks in the interest of answer simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```regex
((?:(?!>).)*>.*?|)(§r)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Replace With:** `$1§r§a`

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/xP8dI5/1

**Sample text**

```
§r O > O §o TEXT §r §o TEXT §r
```

**After Replacment**

```
§r O > O §o TEXT §r§a §o TEXT §r§a
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    §r                      '§r'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: But with code like
         String OriginalMessage = "O§r > O §o TEXT §r §o TEXT §r";
        
        String Message;
        
        Message = OriginalMessage.replaceAll("((?:(?!>).)*>.*?|)(§r)", "§r§a");
        
        System.out.println(Message);

It outputs only "§r§a §o TEXT §r§a"

Answer (score 0):

A pure regex way is by using `\G` like following

```
(\G(?!\A)|>)(.*?)§r
```

and, replace with

```
$1$2§r§a
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xU4eC9/2)**

*Java Code*

```
System.out.println("O§r §r > O §o TEXT §r §o §r TEXT §r".replaceAll("(\\G(?!\\A)|>)(.*?)§r", "$1$2§r§a"));
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/FzDtZq)**